# RewriteEngine for Kohana 3 (Real Estate Portal)

Tags: php, .htaccess, oop, mod-rewrite, kohana

I have real estate portal, where objects has same param:
**- Deal Type: Sale, Rent, Mortage

- Object Type: Flat, Home, Office, Land

- Country, Region, City, District, Street
- Room Count

- Price (min. - max.)

...**

I need to creat Rewrite url
I know I must build rout in **bootstrap.php**
For exp, I have

```
Route::set('objects_list','objects_list(/page<page>)')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'pages',
        'controller' => 'objectslist',
));
```

Web page has:
**www.site.com/objects_list** - show all objects
**www.site.com/objects_list/page(2,3,4...)** - paginator
This two rule is work, but how i can build this **www.site.com/objects_list/rent/home/russia/...**
 and please fix me and tell what url is most correct.

In controller I have default method witch call all objects **get_all($this->data,$this->data['sort'],$pagination->items_per_page,$pagination->offset);** where **$this->data** - is search form array, and I think I must build url based this array.

Answer (score 0):

For **www.site.com/objects_list/rent/home/russia/** url you need to create separate `Route` like:

Route::set('objects_list2','objects_list/(//'),
    array('dealtype' => '(Sale|Rent|Mortage)'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'pages',
        'controller' => 'objectslist2',
));

Pay attention to define `dealtype` part of `Route` to known and only possible dealtype options to clearly match only required URLs.